# Compatibility Issues? ActionBarActivity deprecated in favor of the new AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbaractivity

Will older devices have issues with the new AppCompatActivity?

What is the minimum API Level supported by the new AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can support older device using Appcompat support library till version 7(2.1) which is `Éclair` and higher:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7 //v7 means version 7
```

only device that supports `Éclair` and above will be able to use the [AppCompat support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html).